# Extract line beginning with a specific pattern in sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed, text, regex

My input file is like this:

```
IDno="1"
Name=Jack
Type=Student
IDno="2"
Name=Jill
Type=Teacher
```

I am using sed to extract all the IDno and the type only when type is student.

```
sed -e '/IDno=/b' -e '/Type=Student/b' d
```

This gets me all lines with type student but not the IDnos.

I want to get

```
IDno="1"
Type=Student
IDno="2"
```

but I am getting

```
Type=Student
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't `egrep` be easier?  `egrep -e "IDno=|Type=Student" inputfile`

Comment: Did you mean to write `-e d` (not just `d`)? otherwise the command is malformed I think. Regardless, it would be more idiomatic to invert the logic using `!` rather than by branching past the `d` i.e. `sed '/IDno=\|Type=Student/!d'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`egrep` can get multiple lines from a file.  Using a pipe `|` as a separator you can pull as many different criteria as you want.  `egrep` is the equivalent of `grep -E`.  `egrep` is a script found in the `/bin` folder with the contents pointing to `exec grep -E "$@"`.

Example:

```
egrep "IDno=|Type=Student" inputfile
```

or

```
grep -E "IDno=|Type=Student" inputfile
```

Should output:

```
IDno="1"
Type=Student
IDno="2"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E`, it's time to get rid of the cliché...

Comment: This return every single "IDno=" line, regardless of whether or not the "Type=Student" two lines down. That appeared to be part of the original question, to only return IDno's for "Student"s, but the OP seems to like this, so...?

Comment: That is good, pipeing it back to grep again to only return the ID & Type lines gets rid of the Name too (and the `--` separator line), like adding `|grep "IDno=\|Type="`

Comment: @heemayl Good point!  =)  Old habits die hard I guess.  Maybe one day they'll remove the script, but from my understanding is that it is left in there for older applications that rely on them to not be modified.

Answer (score 5):

With `sed`, to print specific lines, it's easier to use the `-n` option and the `p` command:

```
sed -rn '/IDno=|Type=Student/p'
```

Or:

```
sed -n -e '/IDno=/p' -e '/Type=Student/p'
```

The `-n` option suppresses output unless explicitly print. The `p` command, of course, prints matching lines.

Answer (score 3):

- `awk`:

  Setting the field separator as `=`, and printing the records that contain `Type=Student` as the whole record or `IDno` as the first field:

  ```
  awk -F= '$1=="IDno" || $0=="Type=Student"'
  ```
- `perl`:

  Printing the lines that start with `IDno` followed by `=`, or start with `Type`, followed by a `=` and end in `Student`:

  ```
  perl -ne 'print if /^(IDno=|Type=Student$)/'
  ```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt                                  
IDno="1"
Name=Jack
Type=Student
IDno="2"
Name=Jill
Type=Teacher

% awk -F= '$1=="IDno" || $0=="Type=Student"' file.txt
IDno="1"
Type=Student
IDno="2"

% perl -ne 'print if /^(IDno=|Type=Student$)/' file.txt
IDno="1"
Type=Student
IDno="2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The original question seems to ask *"to extract all the IDno and the type **only when type is student.**"* But the example output returns all IDno= lines, so that's rather contradictory...

Here's an answer that only returns the IDno's and Type's when the Type=Student.

```
sed -n 'N;N;/IDno=.*Type=Student/p' filename | grep -v "^Name="
```

A little explanation:

- `-n, --quiet, --silent`   suppress automatic printing of pattern space
- `N;N;` Read/append the next line of input into the pattern space. (twice)
- `/IDno=.*Type=Student/p` find & print from IDno= to Type=Student
- `| grep -v "^Name="` don't show the Name= line

I don't like the sed|grep, but not too sure how to get sed to re-search it's output, and a pipe generally says "take this output and do something"... Could do grep|sed too

```
grep -v "^Name=" t | sed -n 'N;N;/IDno=.*Type=Student/p'
```

Comment: The example output clarifies that.

Comment: @muru Thanks, I just noticed that too, seems to be a mistake IMO either in the description or example output. Actually found a mistake in my answer too, pasting the Name after ID... Maybe someone will find this answer useful anyway (especially after/if I fix it), I'm still learning from it\

Comment: read it this way "(all the IDno) and (the type only when type is student)"